# error: se requiere un l-valor como operando izquierdo de la asignación ¿?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

Me da ese error el siguiente código, en el bloque "if" usando gcc-avr:

```
uint8_t I2C_Read( uint8_t address, uint8_t registro)
{
    uint8_t status;
    uint16_t conteo= 0;
    uint8_t fin= 0;
    uint8_t leido=0;
    
    TWDR = address<<1; 
    TWDR |= ( 1<<0); //Manda dirección con orden de lectura
    // start transmission of address
    TWCR = (1<<TWINT) | (1<<TWEN);
    // wait for end of transmission
    while( !(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) );
    
    // check if the device has acknowledged the READ / WRITE mode
    status= AtMega328p__TWI_Status();
    if ( status != TW_MR_SLA_ACK) { return 13;} //El dispositivo consultado no responde bien
    
    while ( fin == 0)
    {
        while( !(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)) ); //Espero a que llegue un dato.
        leido= TWDR;
        I2C_Ack();
        
        
        if ( (conteo= registro || conteo= 255)) 
        {
            I2C_Nack();
            I2C_Stop();
            fin= 1;
        }
        else { ++conteo;}
    
    
    return leido;
}
```

Mientras que si compilo una prueba en gcc me la pasa sin problemas, por ejemplo:

```
a= 12;
    b=25;
    x=1025;
    
    if ( (a> 10 || b<30) && ( x> 1024))
    {
        printf( "La expresión funciona bien.\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf( "La expresión funciona bien, estoy en else.\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Hago programación por interés personal y llevaba mucho sin programar y la mitad de las cosas o más se me han olvidad. Se agradece una ayudia.

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La prueba de gcc te compila porque el código es correcto. Sin embargo el ejemplo que pones al principio tiene un par de problemas:

```
if ( (conteo= registro || conteo= 255))
```

A nada que te fijes verás que en ese `if` estás haciendo dos asignaciones, no dos comparaciones. Las comparaciones son con `==`. También puedes aprovechar el cambio para eliminar los paréntesis redundantes:

```
if ( conteo == registro || conteo == 255)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tengo el ojo informático oxidado jajaja.

El caso es que en el ejemplo en gcc pongo la expresión:
```
if ( (a> 10 || b<30) && ( x> 1024))
```
y claro, ahí no hay asignación....

Mil gracias!!!